# Jquery UI autocomplete link to item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to make a search box, where you can search between records in the database.

search.php looks like this:

```
<?php
// connect to mysql
require_once('includes/connect.php');
// include config
include('includes/config.php');

$nameser = $_GET['term'];

$names = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,customerid FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%".$nameser."%' ORDER BY name ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['customerid'];
    $row_array['value'] = htmlentities($row['name']);

    array_push($names,$row_array);
   }

echo json_encode($names);

?>
```

Javascript part looks like this:

```
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          window.location = ("customers.php?action=view&cid=" + item.id)
          //$('#tags').val(ui.item.id);
          //return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a href='customers.php?action=view&cid="+ item.id + "'>"+ item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

However, this gives the error:

```
ReferenceError: item is not defined
```

What I want to happen is, that when I click something in the result list, I get redirected to the url

```
customers.php?action=view&cid={CustomerID}
```

Anyone got an idea?

## **EDIT:**

Correct Javascript code that works:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location = ("customers.php?action=view&cid=" + ui.item.id)
      //$('#tags').val(ui.item.id);
      //return false;
    }
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<a href='customers.php?action=view&cid="+ item.id + "'>"+ item.label + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: Line 5, js: what is item? global variable?

Comment: @Alex: I actually dont know - but it works in Line 13. The script is some copy/paste from other posts here.

Comment: In line 13 `item` is an argument that was passed to function _renderItem, so it's okay. Please post how links look like before `select` event.

Comment: And also try to look in `ui` object, perhaps, it contains selected item

Comment: @Alex: Links looks right in the list. I don't understand how I should look in the ui object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have a demo with a working example in [jsfiddle.  you can see it here:](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/RKajm/)

the key is to get a valid url value in the autoselect select method.  be sure to console.log the ui value so you can see what is available for you to use.  i was able to use the standard ui.item.value value to send the user to another page.

to test my demo:

1.) go into the input box and enter "a".
2.) select "http://www.utexas.edu"
3.) the new page will load.

Comment: Thanks! All I needed to do was to add `ui` to `item.id` and it works!